# Организация кластерного хранилища ceph

Tags: хранилище

Нужно организовать кластер Ceph. Имеются пять серверов, в каждом по четыре HDD. Диски подключены через аппаратный рейд. Понятно, что отказоустойчивость уже достигается программно с помощью самого Ceph, так сказать, ради этого и всё затевается. Вопрос больше в производительности. Какая конфигурация RAID будет лучше с точки зрения производительности при штатном режиме и при ребалансе?
Варианты:
1. Четыре RAID 0. Соответственно 4 OSD на ноду. Всего 20 OSD.
2. Один RAID 1+0. Соответственно 1 OSD на ноду. Всего 5 OSD.
3. Один RAID 0. Соответственно 1 OSD на ноду. Всего 5 OSD.
4. Два RAID 1. ...
Ну, и так далее...

Answer (score 0):

Отказаться от raid контроллера, перешив/заменив его в/на hba.